# Problems to upload a image with selenium python3

Tags: python, selenium, upload

I'm trying upload an image with selenium. The image are uploaded successfully, but I can't click on the button to send.

Follow image bellow...

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import os

#colors
gr = "\033[1;32m"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
print(gr+f"Browser criado")
#Cria browser
driver.get("https://www.metadata2go.com/")
print(gr+f"Site foi aberto")
#Abre site
time.sleep(2)
chooseFile = driver.find_element_by_id("upload")
chooseFile.send_keys("/home/linuxlite/Tiktok/image.jpg")
time.sleep(3)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[text() = "Start Analysing File"]'))).click()


print(gr+f"Imagem enviada com sucesso!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use another locator. The text you are looking for is not in the button, but in the span.

```
//button[contains(@class, 'btn-success start')]
```

or

```
//span[text() = "Start Analysing File"]
```